# Call to undefined method Magento\Framework\Logger\LoggerProxy::setHandlers magento 2.4.2

Tags: log, magento2.4.2

In my custom Magento 2 module I added a custom logger

\Vendor\App\Logger\Logger.php

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\App\Logger;
 
class Logger extends \Monolog\Logger
{
}
```

\Vendor\App\Logger\Handler.php

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\App\Logger;

use Magento\Framework\Filesystem\DriverInterface;
use Monolog\Formatter\LineFormatter;
use Monolog\Handler\StreamHandler;
use Monolog\Logger;
 
class Handler extends \Magento\Framework\Logger\Handler\Base
{
    protected $loggerType = Logger::INFO;
    public $fileName = '';
    public $customfileName = 'NO_PATH';
    protected $_localeDate;

    public function __construct(
        DriverInterface $filesystem,
        \Magento\Framework\Filesystem $corefilesystem,
        \Magento\Framework\Stdlib\DateTime\TimezoneInterface $localeDate,
        $filepath = null
    ) {
        $this->localeDate = $localeDate;
        $corefilesystem = $corefilesystem->getDirectoryWrite(\Magento\Framework\App\Filesystem\DirectoryList::VAR_DIR);
        $logpath = $corefilesystem->getAbsolutePath('log/');
        $filename = 'f24_trace_'. Date('d_m_Y'). '.log';
        $filepath = $logpath . $filename;
        $this->customfileName = $filepath;
        parent::__construct(
            $filesystem,
            $filepath
        );
        //$this->setFormatter(new LineFormatter('%message%'. PHP_EOL, null, true));
    }
}
```

\Vendor\App\etc\di.xml

```
...

     <type name="Vendor\App\Logger\Logger">
            <arguments>
                <argument name="name" xsi:type="string">VendorLogger</argument>
                <argument name="handlers"  xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="system" xsi:type="object">Vendor\App\Logger\Handler</item>
                </argument>
            </arguments>
        </type>

...
```

\Vendor\App\Helper\Data.php

```
<?php
namespace Vendor\App\Helper

class Data extends \Magento\Framework\App\Helper\AbstractHelper
{
    ...
    protected $handler;
    ...

public function __construct(
    ...
    \Vendor\App\Logger\Handler $handler,
    ...
) {
...
 $this->logger->setHandlers ( [$this->handler] );
...
}
```

When I try to install the module in Magento 2.4.2 environment I get this error in Magento logs:

```
 Call to undefined method Magento\Framework\Logger\LoggerProxy::setHandlers() in /var/www/html/app/code/Vendor/App/Helper/Data.php:52
```

any suggestions?
Thanks

Comment: @davide-landoli Have you fixed the issue.

Comment: Actually I commented this line:  $this->logger->setHandlers ( [$this->handler] );
My module is working but no more logging, of course